# HStore and Datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datatables

I have a table on Postgresql called products, that has a hstore column called data. I have a current application which creates an html table out of the hstore keys (which are the table column names, and the hstore values which go under the corresponding columns. Now I'm trying to switch the html table to using datatables.

My original:

```
def index

  @products = Product.all
  @headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq

end
```

then for the index.html.erb, it looks like:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <% @headers.each do |key| %>
          <th><%=  link_to key, :sort => key.downcase %></th>
       <% end %>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <tr>
           <% @headers.each do |key| %>
             <td>
               <%= product.data[key]%>
             </td>
           <% end %>
        </tr>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My new index for the datatables plugin (which is only working for the fixed columns in the Postgresql table, not the hstore one):

```
def index
   @products = Product.all

   respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json=> {
        "sEcho"               => params[:sEcho].to_i,
        "iTotalRecords"       => @products.count,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.count,
        "aaData"              => @products.as_json(
          :only => [:store_id, :created_at, :updated_at]
        )
      }
    end
  end
```

My new index.html.erb looks like:

```
<table id='products' class="display" data-source="<%= store_products_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <% @headers.each do |key| %>
         <th data-column='<%= key.parameterize %>'><%= key %></th>
       <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the aaData to be an array of the values in the data column of the table, similar to how it was before?

I posted the code I thought would help, but I can also provide a sample json that I get, or the jQuery code for the datatables.

Thanks for all help.